# Visual Studio treat custom extension as CSharp

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

I've got files with a custom extension .mcsx that are really CSharp files. I want to get code completion on these files in Visual Studio 2012, but these files are treated as plain text when I open them in VS.

I've tried to create a custom MEF extension which allows me to treat the files as having a content-type based on csharp, but I don't get autocompletion or code formatting for these documents. I might need to invoke the custom CSharp classifier for my custom content type, but I'm not sure. Can anyone help?

The custom ContentType is below:

```
static class ContentType
{
    public const string Name = "CSScript";

    [Export]
    [Name(Name)]
    [DisplayName("CSharp Script")]
    [BaseDefinition("CSharp")]
    public static ContentTypeDefinition CSharpContentType = null;


    [Export]
    [ContentType(Name)]
    [FileExtension(".mcsx")]
    public static FileExtensionToContentTypeDefinition CSharpFileExtension = null;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to 'Ego' on the VS forums:

You can add the custom extension file via the way below:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/08/22/using-custom-file-extension-associations-vstipenv0038.aspx

For more information about Registering a Language Service please view:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb166421(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

So inside of VS things are actually a bit different than the editor APIs imply -- we don't actually use content types (for the most part) to determine when to activate. Noah Richards has a [great blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/noahric/archive/2010/03/01/new-extension-css-is-less.aspx) that shows how to create an extension that marks another extension under an existing editor.

Comment: Jason, Thanks for the link. I've followed the instructions on this blog post, but to no avail. This post was written for VS2010. Has this changed for VS2012 do you think?

Comment: Can you post the .pkgdef file somewhere so I can take a look?